# Example of independent collection $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ s.t. $\sigma (\mathcal A)$ and $\sigma (\mathcal B)$ are not independent.

Tags: probability

A theorem says that if $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are independent $\pi-$system, then $\sigma (\mathcal A)$ and $\sigma (\mathcal B)$ are independent.

I guess it's not true if $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are not $\pi-$system. Does someone knows an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well known example of three events $A,B,C$ such that any two of them are independent but $P(A\cap B\cap C) \neq P(A)P(B)P(C)$. Take $\mathcal A=\{A,B\}$ and $\mathcal B=\{C\}$ to get a counterexample.